# Thunderbird does not forward/attach inline images

Tags: images, html, thunderbird

The problem:

- When I forward/reply_to a message with an **inline image**, the data of that image (the base64 part) **is not sent**. The same happens when i try to attach an image as inline. All these while sending pure HTML message (instead of plain-text) and including the image as attachment on insertion (not attaching it as separate file).

My solution:

- Changing `network.protocol-handler.external.data` to `false`.

  - (Note: By reading [mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.external.%28protocol%29), i suppose an inexistent, image-handling application, was being called.)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `network.protocol-handler.external.data` to `false`.

- (Note: By reading [mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.external.%28protocol%29), i suppose an inexistent, image-handling application, was being called.)

Comment: where did you change this setting?

Comment: Under "Settings", it's called "config editor" at the bottom: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor